# How to pass a custom message/text sent from SNS to use in a Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I created a Lambda function that will publish a message to a slack channel and I have it triggered by an SNS topic. Can I use the SNS subscription filter policy to pass data to my Lambda function so it can be read and used in the Lambda function? I assume Lambda could read the parameters passed from SNS in the Lambda with using event?

```
event['message']
```

I just don't want to create a Lambda function for each trigger I will create. I want to have one Lambda function, pass in the custom text from separate SNS topics therefore making the function reusable.

I have one SNS topic for CodeDeploy passing and one for it failing. I want to just pass in the message "CodeDeploy passed" or "CodeDepoy failed" into the Lambda function.

Thanks for any help or advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger your Lambda function with [CloudWatch Events with Event Patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html). This way you can specify the event that your Lambda function will receive (constant or parts of the source event).

Here is an example for a 'SUCCESS' with CodeDeploy:
[image]

You can achieve what you want using a single rule matching both 'SUCCESS' and 'FAILURE' and a logic in your Lambda function based on the source event or part of it to create a Slack message.

Comment: That is what I wound up doing - creating a rule in Cloudwatch. I used this to monitor my code pipeline. I have this in my Event source - The I learned to use the 'event' as the variable that held the message in the Lambda event.